# Can this transaction code be written in batchupdate format?

Tags: flutter, dart

Can someone please help me to write this transaction as in batchupdate format. It updates 2 values at a time I'm facing some weird issues like one of them is not getting updated at the time. So I guess something like batchupdate will work fine here. I'm a newbie at this stuff on couldn't seem do it by myself so please a little help would be appreciated.

```
Firestore.instance
                    .runTransaction((Transaction transaction) async {
                  DocumentSnapshot snapshot =
                      await transaction.get(student.documents[i].reference);
                  await transaction
                      .update(snapshot.reference, {'bool': !snapshot['bool']});
                  refresh();
                  student.documents[i].data['bool']
                      ? await transaction.update(
                          snapshot.reference, {'att': snapshot['att'] - 1})
                      : await transaction.update(
                          snapshot.reference, {'att': snapshot['att'] + 1});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done with a `WriteBatch` instead of a transaction. The reason being is that you are only performing writes on a single document reference. What does `refresh()` do? You can actually replace the entire transaction with a single call to [`updateData()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/updateData.html).

Comment: refresh() is typo...I remove it from there later ..nvm that.. using updateData So here is what's wrong currently
- I click on widget, so if the client and server both have base value 4  BOTH update to 5 and 5 respectively  and updates in real-time(updating value stored in field of a document of some collection) WHICH is the right behaviour 
- BUT when i change the value to lets say 10  of that field in server, the client (my lutter app) does not update its value +++ AND when i click on it click on client now it updates value 4->5 on server instead of 10->11  WHICH is not the behavior i want